# Word VBA Move the focus to the target of Selection.Find.Execute

Tags: vba, ms-word, full-text-search, focus

In word, I can not get the focus to move to the target of
Selection.Find.Execute (findText)

In a word document I have one button that moves the top item from the list of things to do down to a logbook section.
The code to move the item is below; bMoveToLog. Focus stays with the list of things to do. Now I want a button that moves focus down to the logbook following the title "MYLOG" so I can do my timesheets.

There is a list of options I have tried.

How do I move the focus to the target of Selection.Find.Execute?

```
Private Sub bMoveToLog_Click()
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, which:=wdGoToAbsolute
    findText = "TODO"
    Selection.Find.Execute (findText)
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Cut
    findText = "MYLOG"
    Selection.Find.Execute (findText)
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=2, Extend:=wdMove
    Selection.InsertDateTime
    Selection.InsertBefore ("   ")
    Selection.Paste
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, which:=wdGoToAbsolute
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub bViewLog_Click()
    findText = "MYLOG"
    myRange = Selection.Find.Execute(findText)
    myRange.Select '*** This doesn't work - how do I set focus
End Sub
```

Options tried

```
'various attempts
    'Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=2
    'Selection.GoToEditableRange wdEditorCurrent
    'myRange.Select
    'Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToPage, which:=wdGoToAbsolute
    'Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=2, Extend:=wdMove
    'ActiveSheet.Range("D5").Select
'This works but doesn't use search
    'Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Count:=6
```

Answer (score 1):

Debugging showed that the search in the ViewLog routine was not performing its job. The search wasn't performed. That was why focus was not left where expected.
It was fixed by adding a Selection.Goto statement before the search to put focus on the page.

New View-Log routine is;

```
Private Sub bViewLog_Click()
    'Selection.GoTo is needed to put focus on a page
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, which:=wdGoToAbsolute
    findText = "MYLOG"
    Selection.Find.Execute (findText)
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=2, Extend:=wdMove
End Sub
```